# can't connect some IP addresses via 'telnet 217.168.180.104 18000' ; telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: firewall, tcp-ip

I can't connect some IP addresses via 'telnet 217.168.180.104 18000' ;  gives below errors:
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused..socket connect error.
ufw desabled, the configuration of mikrotik( 217.168.180.104) is right.
please, give any reccomendation....to solve ths problem..

```
raul@raul-Aspire-E1-572G:~$ telnet 217.168.180.104 18000
Trying 217.168.180.104...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
raul@raul-Aspire-E1-572G:~$ netstat --numeric-ports -l | grep 18000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
raul@raul-Aspire-E1-572G:~$ netstat --numeric-ports -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18180           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:631       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35145           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40317           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49663           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50246           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54575           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 [::]:59885              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:5353               [::]:*                             
raw6       0      0 [::]:58                 [::]:*                  7          
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43563    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1730
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53g8t.png)

Comment: Is this IP address supposed to respond to the TCP port you mentioned?

Comment: What are IP addresses of both sides of the telnet connection? Are both the same? Possible problem may be in local firewall. Please, append here output of these commands: `ip route` (from both the listening server and the connecting client), `sudo iptables-save`, `sudo iptables-save | grep 18000` from the server, `telnet localhost 18000` from the server.

Comment: yes, this is router IP address of nanometrics Centaur equpment.

Comment: no, difference IP addresses.

Comment: the parameters of firewall of router are: Discovery
IP address: 224.199.71.138
Port number: 6776

Ethernet:
Static IP address: 192.168.88.10
Static subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Static default gateway: 192.168.88.1

SeedLink Server:
IP: 217.168.180.104
port number: 18000

Comment: ufw status is inactive